# Facebook share for subpages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have index.php for my home page. I added following code

```
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://example.com/SITE/" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="My title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="My description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://example.com/SITE/img/facebook-share.jpg" />
```

and next after body tag

```
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

it work's fine. But I have other page like confirm.php. I added the same code as above but I change url to `example.com/SITE/confirm`. I changed title, description and image url. But the thing is, I want to use php variable so my code for confirm.php looks like this

```
     <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.example.com/SITE/cofirm?passkey=<?php echo $confirm_code; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="My title - confirm" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="My description <?php echo $car_name; ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://example.com/SITE/img/facebook-share-2.jpg" />
```

but it's not working. When I want to share confirm.php page it tooks meta og from index.php. How Can I separate facebook share for my subpages. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the URL to the page that is not working?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it. But for now, I can't pass variable to my meta tag. It gives me variable name instead of value

Comment: @WizKid small update. I can now pass my php variable to PC meta tag. When I open source code in my browser I can see proper informations inside tags. But when I copy site address and paste it to facebook og:description which contains variable value seems to be empty. How? Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Check in the Facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: @WizKid I tried. It shows empty description too. I don’t know how to get it work :/

Comment: And without knowing what you are doing it is impossible for us to help you. We need the URL.

Comment: @WizKid could you e-mail me? I really dont want to share url. My e-mail - icek9.2@wp.pl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163669/discussion-between-mmpl1-and-wizkid).

Comment: "cofirm" - type only in the question, or on the real page too?

Comment: @luschn I dont understand you

Comment: check your og:url. shouldn´t it be "confirm" instead of "cofirm"? could explain the issue.

Comment: @luschn it doesn't help :/ I can see og:description in source code, but no on facebook